# How to make simple 2 category filter?

Tags: javascript, html

**What I'm trying to do**: I'm making a simple website for my employer and they want all their products listed. They also want the products filter-able by type (i.e. canned food, dry food, leashes, flea away, etc) and brand (i.e. Blue Buffalo, Wellness, Natural Balance, etc). I don't know how to do the filter at all while not screwing up the lightbox codes. Athough I don't know who exactly did this code, I'm looking for something like this -http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/8BL5q/3/ -where when you choose an option, only anything with that class or id or whatever will show. I need users to be able to filter it first by brand, then by type.

**NOTE**: I prefer it in JavaScript and a separate JS file so I can just link it to the pages that need it, but if you have a more simple way, great. I can't change any of the CSS; all the spacing is perfect for all but one major browser and even pretty decent so far for mobile devices. Also, you should know that I only have a ***very basic*** knowledge of HTML and CSS. I know pretty much nothing of PHP, JS, etc. So if it's convenient for you, please explain to me why you code what you code and exactly where I put these codes relative to exiting codes. Thanks in advance everyone.

Here's what I have in HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
NAVIGATION CODES
<div class="content">
<div class="sidebar1">
<form name="form" id="form">
<select name="brand" id="brand" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value="all4pets_dogs.html" id="filter-none">FILTER BY BRAND</option>
<option value="all4pets_dogs.html" id="filter-againstthegrain">Against the Grain</option>
<option value="all4pets_dogs.html" id="filter-bynature">By Nature</option>
<option value="all4pets_dogs.html" id="filter-californianatural">California Natural</option>
<option value="all4pets_dogs.html" id="filter-canidae">Canidae</option>
<option value="all4pets_dogs.html" id="filter-chickensoup">Chicken Soup for the Soul</option>
</select>
</form>
<h3>Don't see what you want? We make special orders!</h3>
<!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
<h4>Dogs</h4>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/againstthegrain_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Against the Grain canned dog food<br />12oz"><img src="images/againstthegrain_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="againstthegrain" alt="Against the Grain canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">Against the Grain<br />
Canned Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/bynature95_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="By Nature 95% canned dog food<br />13.2oz"><img src="images/bynature95_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="bynature" alt="By Nature 95% canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">By Nature 95%<br />
Canned Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/bynatureentree_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="By Nature Entrees canned dog food<br />13oz"><img src="images/bynatureentree_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="bynature" alt="By Nature Entrees canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">By Nature Entrees<br />
Canned Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/bynatureorganics_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="By Nature Organics canned dog food<br />4lb"><img src="images/bynatureorganics_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="bynature" alt="By Nature Organics canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">By Nature Organics<br />
Dry Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/canatural_dry.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="California Natural dry dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/canatural_dry_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="californianatural" alt="California Natural dry"/></a>
<div class="text_line">California Natural<br />
Dry Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/canatural_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="California Natural canned dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/canatural_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="californianatural" alt="California Natural canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">California Natural<br />
Canned Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/canatural_treats.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="California Natural dry dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/canatural_treats_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="californianatural" alt="California Natural treats"/></a>
<div class="text_line">California Natural<br />
Treats<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/canidae_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Canidae canned dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/canidae_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="canidae" alt="Canidae canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">Canidae<br />
Canned Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/canidae_dry.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Canidae dry dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/canidae_dry_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="canidae" alt="Canidae dry"/></a>
<div class="text_line">Canidae<br />
Dry Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/chickensoup_can.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Chicken Soup canned dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/chickensoup_can_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="chickensoup" alt="Chicken Soup for the Soul canned"/></a>
<div class="text_line">Chicken Soup for the Soul<br />
Canned Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="imgthumbhold"><a href="images/chickensoup_dry.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Chicken Soup dry dog food<br />5lb"><img src="images/chickensoup_dry_thmb.png" class="imgthumb" id="chickensoup" alt="Chicken Soup for the Soul dry"/></a>
<div class="text_line">Chicken Soup for the Soul<br />
Dry Dog Food<br />
</div>
</div>
<!-- end .content --></div>
<div class="footer">
<p>&copy;2013 Dark Wolf Designs</p>
<!-- end .footer --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Lolz man, looks like here is someone to do your work. This is a community to help each other. Please don't ask this type of task. If you wanna try some code we are here to help you. Let us know what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry man. HADI is right. You are asking us to code something for you. We are here to teach and learn, not to do all the work for you. Look for a freelancer. It sounds like an easy job so it should be cheap.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've done the entire site pretty much by myself. The filter is the only problem now, and I've tried learning how it on my own. I'm at a loss because JS is very confusing to me and JS seems to be the only way. I _did_ ask to explain why and what you code so I can learn the whats and whys and do it myself in the future. I don't know how to explain what JS I've tried because I'm still confused about it. If it helps, I've tried making the id, rel, alt, and class attributes in the appropriate lightboxes match up with the respective option tag attributes in the form.